# Enumerate available WiFi Printers in my Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, printing, windows-phone-8

I know similar questions have been asked a lot, ie "can I print from my wp8?". Most folks seem content with the simple "no" response.  I am looking to add this functionality into my app and I know it can be accomplished at some level - even if I can only support a very minimum printer set for now.

I've looked at the app [PrintHand](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=2c7bea79-2ea9-435c-8443-66fec76b5153), and it appears to have the capabilities I need: print to wireless and Bluetooth printers.

I've been looking through the [Bluetooth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) scenarios document a bit and I think this might help discover a Bluetooth printer. That's a start. Perhaps it will help in identifying wireless printers also.

I realize I need to start very small with this project and I want to first try to enumerate any *wireless* printers (I don't have a Bluetooth one yet) available on the current network. Would anybody happen to have a pointer in the right direction on how to get started or better yet, some related sample code?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to detect a nearby wireless printer using Simple Service Discovery Protocol.

Here is my sample function:

```
private const string SSDP_IP = "239.255.255.250";
private const string SSDP_PORT = "1900";

public async static void DiscoverAsync2()
{       
    var multicastIP = new HostName(SSDP_IP);
    var found = false;

    using (var socket = new DatagramSocket())
    {
        socket.MessageReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var reader = e.GetDataReader();
            var bytesRemaining = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
            var receivedString = reader.ReadString(bytesRemaining);

            // TODO: something useful with this new info

            found = true;
        };

        await socket.BindEndpointAsync(null, string.Empty);
        socket.JoinMulticastGroup(multicastIP);

        while (true)
        { 
            found = false;

            using (var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(multicastIP, SSDP_PORT))
            {
                var request = new StringBuilder();
                request.AppendLine("M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1");
                request.AppendLine("HOST: " + SSDP_IP + ":" + SSDP_PORT);
                request.AppendLine("MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"");
                request.AppendLine("MX: 3");
                request.AppendLine("ST: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:Printer:1"); // use ssdp:all to get everything
                request.AppendLine(); // without this extra blank line, query won't run properly
                var buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.ToString());

                await stream.WriteAsync(buff.AsBuffer());

                await Task.Delay(5000);

                if (!found)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i didn't get any error , how can i show wireless printer am new to c# .

Comment: This will enumerate UPnP printers (which I've found there aren't very many of). Many newer printers implement some form of IPP and are discoverable via multicast dns requests (not addressed with the above solution). There are a few zeroconfig libraries available for Windows you can find with a web search.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can give is my Github Repo which isn't related to Wifi printers, but Google cloud printing.

There isn't really a .net reference for using Google Cloud Print in their documentation, but the code works in Mono, and should be easy to move over to .NET and hence, Windows Phone.

[MonoGCP](https://github.com/slackshot/MonoGCP)

Comment: You can also look at making a class for Printer Command Language, but I know that the knowledge base is pretty intense to develop.. and people who have sat down and mastered it.. well.. they do pretty well, and it becomes their career.  It's also something very hard to research online and figure out.

Comment: PCL won't help much until I can identify and contact a printer. Thanks though.

Comment: SNMP would probably assist you in finding printers in your network.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking into SNMP and Sockets as possibilities.